# WebStorm autocomplete React JSX component with required props on NEW LINES

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, webstorm, jsx

At the moment WebStorm can autocomplete a component name and adds the required props automatically, for example

```
// currently does
<SomeComponent name={} id={} blah1={} blah2={} />
```

My issue is some components have many props and I'd prefer WebStorm outputs the autocomplete component with required props on new lines

```
// I want it to do
<SomeComponent 
  name={} 
  id={}
  blah1={}
  blah2={} 
/>
```

How can I accomplish this? I'm actually on IntelliJ if that makes a difference.

Comment: use prettier https://prettier.io/  https://prettier.io/docs/en/webstorm.html

Answer (score 4):

To have your code formatted in this way, go to **Preferences | Editor | Code Style | HTML** and set **Wrap attributes** to `Wrap always` and and **New line before first attribute** to `When multiline`

Comment: Hmm. Still doing the same thing for me of putting all props all same line, even with these set

Comment: @BrianSchermerhorn works after Ctrl+Alt+L key combination has been pressed.